# Trying to use JFileChooser to select a folder

Tags: java

I'm trying to use JFileChooser to select a folder.  It returns the parent folder, not the current folder.
Example I select folder documents, then backup.  JFileChooser returns documents instad of backup.

```
String getFilePath()
{

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

//  fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));  
      fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File rt=fc.getCurrentDirectory();   
            String t=rt.getName();
            return t;
        }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use getSelectedFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using [`JFileChooser.getCurrentDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getCurrentDirectory--) instead of [`JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile--).